# Playing for another country

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

[Dirk Nannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Nannes), a former Netherlands cricketer now plays for the Australian Cricket team. How is it possible for a single player to play for more than one country. What are the rules for such a scenario?

Comment: For Dirk Nannes, I thought one of his parents was Australian, but I am not sure.

Comment: His parents were Dutch. They migrated to Australia before he was born. Therefore, he owns dual citizenship and carries both, the Dutch and the Australian passports.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the current rules set by ICC, a player is prohibited from representing one country if they have represented another ICC Member at Under 19 level or above, in an ICC sanctioned* match (Test matches, ODIs, ICC Global or regional event) in the immediately preceding four years.

*ICC Sanctioned - This only includes the national Under 19 teams in the Under 19 World Cup or any direct qualifying competition for same and the full national side in Tests, ODIs and Twenty20 Internationals. In other words, it does not include under-19 matches played outside the framework of the World Cup, or any national sides outside the full first XI, such as A teams and the like.

There have been a few players that have represented two countries over the years.

[List of players that have represented two nations in Test matches.](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283699.html)

[List of players that have represented two nations in ODIs.](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283476.html)

[List of players that have represented two nations in T20Is.](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/pakistan/content/records/485107.html)

Note: Nannes and Morgan represented 2 nations within the stipulated 4 years. This is because there is a clause stating that players are not disqualified from playing for any Test-playing nation if they are representing ICC Associate members. This allowed Nannes to quit Netherlands and play for Australia and for Morgan to quit Ireland and play for England. However, once a player plays for a Test-playing nation, they would need to wait to re-qualify (4 years) for any future appearances for associate members.

Comment: The ICC can also grant one-off exemptions to the 4 year qualification period, as happened with Ed Joyce.